# recording in slow motion (camera) with cordova for ionic 2 app

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova, ionic2

I am trying to find the parameters and the right plugin to use the camera tool in slow motion with cordova, with the aim to develop an app with ionic 2.

I found this plugin : 
[Github link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture)

But I do not find how to use the slow motion (in iphone 240 fps with the iphone 6 and more, which could be useful for video analysis app).

Thank you